# Why is my Atmega644 TIMER0 running at half the speed of the expected clock speed?

Tags: c, timer, microcontroller, clock, atmel

I am trying to build a drum machine using an Atmega644. The drum machine will have 16 LED's which will show which 16th of the beat it is at. The user should be able to set the BPM and therefore the updating of the LED will be different for different BPM.

I have a 16 MHz Crystal set at XTAL1 and XTAL2. I used a FUSE calculator to write the FUSE bits to a "Full Swing Oscillator" and remove the internal clock divide 8. I then set up the TIMER0 to perform this task

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL  // 1MHz internal clock

unsigned int tempo = 250; // Default BPM of 120.
volatile unsigned int seq_timer = 0;


//set-up timer for 0.5 ms update
TIMSK0 = (1<<OCIE0A);
TCCR0A = (1 << WGM01) |(1<<WGM00);
TCCR0B = (0 << WGM02) | (0<< CS02) | (1 << CS01) | (1 << CS00); //divide by 64
OCR0A = 125;

ISR (TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {
if (seq_timer>0) {seq_timer--;}
}

//Update which 16th note we are at.
void step(void){
update_led();
step_number = step_number < 15 ? step_number +1 : 0;
}

//Shift the LED such that the LED corresponding to step_number is lit up.
void update_led(void) {
for (int j = 16; j>=0; j--)
{
    if ((((1 << step_number))>>j) & 0x01) {
        PORTD |= (1 << PD5); //Serial Input
    }
    else {
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PD5);
    }
    PORTD |= (1 << PD4); //Read clock 
    PORTD &= ~(1<< PD4);  
}
    PORTD |= (1 << PD3); //Shift clock 
    _delay_ms(40);
    PORTD &= ~(1 << PD3);
}


while (1) 
{   
  if ((seq_timer == 0)) {    
     seq_timer = tempo;
     step();
 }
```

Step functions calls a "update_led()" function which light up the LED corresponding to the step_number. This should according to my calculations occur (16e6 / (64*250*125)) = 8 updates/sec. But instead it does 4 updates/sec.

Am I missing something crucial?

Comment: Why have you not just umm.. 'adjusted' the numbers by 2 and carried on developing?

Comment: Because I want to understand why it does what it does.

Comment: But I think I found the error, I had set the WGM00 < 1. Which should be set to 0 to have a CTC Timer.